# Need help with SQL 2000 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

This is my logic.

I have an articles table and a matching images tables. The images are stored in binary format. Each image table has 2 instances of each image, this is because I have 2 sizes. 300 x 200 and 500 x 400 with their rows separated by ImageSize

I want to write a stored procedure that checks if ImageSize=3 is available and if not, then retrieve from ImageSize=2.

How can I set up my stored procedure to do this?

Thanks

Comment: include your table structure in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andomar's response is completely valid and very elegant - if you want something more "down to earth", that takes into account there might be other number values involved in the future, try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FetchImage(@ImageName VARCHAR(255))
AS
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.ImageTable
             WHERE ImageName = @ImageName AND ImageSize = 3)
      SELECT
          Image
      FROM
          dbo.ImageTable
      WHERE
          ImageName = @ImageName AND ImageSize = 3
   ELSE
      SELECT
          Image
      FROM
          dbo.ImageTable
      WHERE
          ImageName = @ImageName AND ImageSize = 2
```

That basically does the same thing - but it'll continue to return the `Image` for `ImageSize = 3` even if you suddenly also have image sizes codes of 4, 5, and so forth.

Comment: @TOm: I don't like the fact that if some other value (like ImageSize=4) is introduced, Andomar's solution will fail. That's why I like to be more specific and clearer in my intent. Elegant is great - but "it works" (in all cases) is more important to me.

Comment: If that were the case, surely you'd just use Andomar's solution with the addition of "AND ImageSize BETWEEN 2 and 3" to the WHERE clause??

Comment: @Tom: that might be a possibility, yes.

Comment: I think this would be my best solution. I am not searching for the largest, I need code that can search for largest and if that fails gets the second best option. This is because I am displaying different sized based on the page am on. So I don't want to have a null image section.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the highest size image with a simple `top 1`:

```
create procedure dbo.GetImage(
    @ImageName varchar(50))
as
select  top 1 image
from    ImageTable
where   ImageName = @ImageName
order by
        ImageSize desc
```

Comment: Dynamic sql is usually bad - sounds like there is no need for that now.

Comment: This is NOT dynamic sql, just a sql-statement (in a procedure) that uses a parameter.